# using directive and abstract method

Tags: c++

I have a class (let's call it A) the inherits an interface defining several abstract methods and another class there to factor in some code (let's call it B).

The question is, I have an abstract method in the interface that A implements just to call the B version. Is there a way to use the keyword using to avoid writing a dull method like:

```
int A::method() override
{
  return B::method();
}
```

I tried writing in A using B::method, but I still get an error that A doesn't implement the abstract method from the interface.
Is there a special technique to use in the case or am I just out of luck? (and if so, is there a specific reason why it should be that way?).

Thanks.

edit:
To clarify, the question is, why isn't it possible to just do this:

```
class A: public Interface, public B {
  using B::method;
};
```

Comment: I assume one of `method` and `methode` is a typo, right?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: having *real* code that actually exhibits the *problem* would help, but the short is I don't see how `using` anything will solve what you seem to want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make this clear. You basically have the following problem, right?

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

struct B
{
    void method()
    {
        // implementation of Interface::method
    }
};

struct A : Interface, B
{
     // some magic here to automatically
     // override Interface::method and 
     // call B::method
};
```

This is simply **impossible**, because the fact that the methods have the same names is irrelevant from a technical point view. In other word's, `Interface::method` and `B::method` are simply not related to each other, and their identical names are not more than a coincidence, just like someone else called "Julien" doesn't have anything to do with you just because you share the same first name.

You are basically left with the following options:

1.) Just write the call manually:

```
struct A : Interface, B
{
    virtual void method()
    {
        B::method();
    }
};
```

2.) Minimise writing work with a macro, so that you can write:

```
struct A : Interface, B
{
    OVERRIDE(method)
};
```

But I would strongly recommend against this solution. Less writing work for you = more reading work for everyone else.

3.) Change the class hierarchy, so that `B` implements `Interface`:

```
struct Interface
{
    virtual void method() = 0;
};

struct B : Interface
{
    virtual void method()
    {
        // implementation of Interface::method
    }
};

struct A : B
{
};
```

Answer (score -1):

if `B::method` is abstract you cannot call it because is not implemented... has no code.

An example:

```
class A
{
  public:
    virtual void method1( ) = 0;
    virtual void method2( ){ }
};

class B : public A
{
  public:
    virtual void method1( ) override
    { return A::method1( ); } // Error. A::method1 is abstract

    virtual method2( ) override
    { return A::method2( ); } // OK. A::method2 is an implemented method
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even if there were a way to do what you want, in the name of the readability of your code, I would not recommend that.

If you do not put the "B::" before "method" call, when I read that, I would say it is a recursive call.